# Stretching TableLayout inside ScrollView

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview, tablelayout

I have this TableLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalView" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/reportTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
    </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

I have set all layout_width to fill_parent, and yet my Table columns don't seem to stretch and fill the rest of the width space. There is still a margin on the left, but I want my table to stretch over the complete width of the screen. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: how many columns are in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one column, `android:stretchColumns="1"` won't do anything, because the number represents the index of the column to stretch (with 0 being the index of the first column).  Try using `android:stretchColumns="*"`

**EDIT:**  thinking about this a little more, I doubt `fill_parent` will actually have any effect on the `horizontalScrollView`.  Because the view is infinitely scrollable in the horizontal direction, I don't think android takes the `layout_width` into account unless it is a hard-coded value.  You can try setting the `layout_width` to the same size as your screen (maybe get the width of your screen and set it as a minimum width in code?).

Comment: ok understand your EDIT. Will try to set it in code then. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I got it. The answer is: Set this in ScrollView:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: nice catch, I didn't know about this property.  Thanks!